# WPF to WCF returns 'The HTTP request was forbidden' with large file upload

Tags: wcf, iis-10

We have a WPF application that connects to a WCF Web Service...

IIS 10 on Server 2016

If a user tries to upload a large(ish) file it will return

```
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
```

We have been able to reproduce this error with a pdf file of 23,486,000 bytes but so far have been unable to pin it down.

The maxReceivedMessageSize in Web.config is set to 524,288,000 bytes and IIS Request Filtering is set to the default 30,000,000 bytes

Making the assumption that file size is causing this as it's the only time the error is thrown...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you are accessing the WCF service through a proxy server, it might be a limitation of the proxy server

Comment: Nope - no proxy server